# In Jenkins pipeline, how to set a value for an environment variable when loading a shared library?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multi-branch pipeline that uses a `Jenkinsfile` to load a shared library defined in my system configuration.

```
@Library("my-shared-library") _
import com.company.exa.builders.BaseBuilder
import com.company.exa.builders.EdiBuilder
import hudson.model.*

buildNumbers = getBuildNumbers() // Function not shown, but it works

properties ([
  disableConcurrentBuilds(),
  [$class: 'jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty',
   strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator',
              numToKeepStr: '50',
              artifactNumToKeepStr: '20']],
  parameters ([
    choiceParam(name: "VERSION_CHOICE",
                choices: buildNumbers,
                description: "Version from Builds"),
    stringParam(name: "VERSION_PASSEDIN",
                defaultValue: env.BRANCH_NAME,
                description: "Passed-in version. Note this will override VERSION_CHOICE."),
    booleanParam(name: "UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS",
                 defaultValue: false,
                 description: "Upload artifacts to file servers?"),
    choiceParam(name: "DEBUG_LEVEL",
                choices: ["0", "1", "2", "3"],
                description: "Debug level; 0=less verbose, 3=most verbose")
    ])
])
```

When I run it clicking `Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now`, I get

```
00:00:01.018  Loading library my-shared-library
00:00:01.019  Attempting to resolve maser from remote references...
00:00:01.019   > git --version # timeout=10
00:00:01.023   > git --version # 'git version 2.17.1'
00:00:01.023  using GIT_SSH to set credentials Jenkins Master SSH
00:00:01.028   > git ls-remote -h -- git@bitbucket.org:cfouts-kmha/kmha-infrastructure.git # timeout=10
00:00:01.546  Found match: refs/heads//master revision a1bc1e273b41c4e892d7c25814d0f2a1c261f7e5
00:00:01.546  ERROR: Checkout failed
00:00:01.546  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null value not allowed as an environment variable: VERSION_PASSEDIN
00:00:01.546    at hudson.EnvVars.put(EnvVars.java:379)
00:00:01.546    at hudson.model.StringParameterValue.buildEnvironment(StringParameterValue.java:59)
```

...complaining that variable `VERSION_PASSEDIN` is null. I've tried setting the `VERSION_PASSEDIN`variable to just `""` in the following locations to no avail...

- The multi-branch pipeline's Folder properties
- The multi-branch pipeline's parent folder properties
- In the Jenkinsfile itself
- In the System configuration global properties

Any clues on how to fix this? I have a feeling it's something obvious that I'm not seeing.

Note that if I run the job with a branch's "Build with parameters" link, the job runs fine.

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear. `VERSION_PASSEDIN` is a pipeline parameter and neither an environment variable nor accessible in the shared library scope according to the code in the question. Could you please update with at least the relevant shared library class method or global variable declaration, and an example of usage in the shared library definition code?

Answer (score 0):

You have a chicken-and-egg problem when trying to set default value for parameters, e.g. here:

```
stringParam(name: "VERSION_PASSEDIN",
                defaultValue: env.BRANCH_NAME,
```

To run your pipeline, Jenkins needs to figure out the value of the parameters. However, to figure out the value of the parameters, Jenkins needs to run your pipeline. See the problem?

To overcome this problem, here's what happens: Jenkins assumes the value of nothing for both `VERSION_CHOICE` and `VERSION_PASSEDIN`. In the first case, it's an empty choice; in the second, it's `null`.

Comment: But I set a `VERSION_PASSEDIN` variable in several places?

Comment: Then you have a chicken-and-several-eggs problem. Still, before running any of the places, parameters need to be set.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/71456982/2047614