# Declarative Pipeline using env var as choice parameter value

Tags: groovy, parameters, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

Disclaimer: I can achieve the behavior I’m looking for with Active Choices plugin, BUT I really want this to work in a Jenkinsfile and controlled with scm because it’s tedious to configure the Active Choices on each job we may need them on. And with it being separate from the Jenkinsfile creation, it’s then one job defined in multiple places. :(

I am looking to verify ***if this is possible***, because I can’t get the syntax right, if it is possible. And I haven’t been able to find any examples online:

```
pipeline {
    environment { 
        ARTIFACTS = lib.myfunc() // this works well
    }
    parameters {
        choice(name: "Artifacts", choices: ARTIFACTS) // I can’t get this to work
    }
}
```

I cannot use the function inline in the declaration of the parameter. The errors were clear about that, but it seems as though I should be able to do what I’ve written out above.

I am not home, so I do not have the exceptions handy, but I will add them soon. They did not seem very helpful while I was working on this yesterday.

What have I tried?

I’ve tried having the the function return a List Because it requires a list according to the docs, and I’ve also tried (illogically) returning a String in the precise syntax of a list of strings. (It was hacky, like `return "['" + artifacts.join("', '") + "']"` to look like `['artifact1.zip', 'artifact2.zip']`

I also tried things like `"$ARTIFACTS"` and `${ARTIFACTS}` in desperation.

Answer (score 1):

```
the list of choices has to be supplied as String containing new line characters (\n): choices: 'TESTING\nSTAGING\nPRODUCTION'
```

I was tipped off by this article:
https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines

Related to a bug:

https://issues.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-40358

:shrug:

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to understand that Jenkins starts running your pipeline code by presenting you with `Parameters` page. Once you've set up the parameters, and pressed `Build`, *then* a node is allocated, variables are set, and your code starts to run.

But in your pipeline, as presented above, you want to run some code *to prepare the parameters*.

This is not how Jenkins usually works. It's definitely *not* doing the following: allocating a node, setting the variables, running some of your code until `parameters` clause is reached, stopping all that, presenting you with GUI, and then continuing where it left off. Again, it's **not** how Jenkins works.

This is why, when writing a new pipeline, your first option to build it is `Build` and not `Build with Parameters`. Jenkins hasn't run your code yet; it doesn't have any idea if there *are* any parameters. When running for the first time, it will remember the parameters (and any choices, if were) as were configured for this (first) run, so in the second run you will see the parameters as configured *in the first run*. (Generally, in run number `n` you will see the result of configuration in run number `n-1`.)

There are a number of ways to overcome this.

If having a "somewhat recent" (and not "current and absolutely up-to-date") situation fits you, your code may need minor changes to work — *second* time. (I don't know what exactly `lib.myfunc()` returns but if it's a choice of `Development`/`Staging`/`Production` this might be good enough.)

If having a "somewhat recent" situation is an absolute no-no (e.g. your `lib.myfunc()` returns the list of `git` branches, and "list of branches as of yesterday" is unacceptable), then your only solution is ActiveChoice. ActiveChoice allows you to run some code *before* showing you the `Build with Parameters` GUI (with script approval etc.).

Comment: Running the code works fine, I commented as such to the right of that line. It was the setting of the parameter that was wonky. I was able to fix it with a workaround based on a bug I found. Details are on the answer I wrote to my own question.