# How to use a Jenkins sshagent plugin in an "Extensible choice parameter" in a job's configuration?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created a Jenkins pipeline job, I did...

```
New Item 
    -> Give name and choose Pipeline 
    -> Click Ok 
    -> Click This project is parameterized 
    -> Click Add Parameter 
    -> Choose Extensible Choice Parameter 
    -> Provide parameter name 
    -> Choose System Groovy Choice Parameter as Choice provider
```

In the "Groovy Script" section, I want to do this

```
    sshagent(["ssh-creds"]) {
        def test = sh(script: """
                          git ls-remote -h -t git@bitbucket.mycompany/myRepo.git
                      """,
                      returnStdout: true)
        println test
    }
```

Here's a screen shot
[image]

However, I get the following when I run the script

```
Failed to execute script
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.sshagent() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList, Script1$_run_closure1) values: [[ssh-creds], Script1$_run_closure1@d87d2fe]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
...
```

How do I use the `sshagent` plugin here? (I use the above code in a Jenkinsfle, but it doesn't work here.)

Or a more generic question, how can I access my Git repos using SSH in this case?

Comment: Code that runs in ActiveChoice is not Pipeline code. You can't do things that require node allocation (like `sh` etc.).

Comment: @MaratC, thanks, I figured that by now. I updated my OP with a more general question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71456982/2047614. In a similar situation to yours, we have an internal server that exposes an API getting what we want (list of repos, in your case), and ActiveChoice parameter that has Groovy code that has Javascript code. The JS code invokes an API endpoint and parses the results.